# Not able to receive notification from firebase in swift3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3

I am not able to receive the notification from firebase. I have updated all pods and also uploaded the APNs Certificates for production. In Xcode i am managing the provisioning profile automatically and also enabled push notification, Remote notification(inside Background modes) in capabilities. Notification is enabled in setting section of device.
Here is my code in App delegate.

```
 import UserNotifications
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseInstanceID
 import FirebaseMessaging

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    FirebaseApp.configure()

 }

func application(_ application: UIApplication,     
      didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

     Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,   
  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
  Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    Messaging.messaging().connect { error in

    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
 extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    //Here i do my navigation according to notification type
 }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
 }

 extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
//MARK: FCM Token Refreshed
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    def.setValue(token, forKey: KDeviceToken)
    print(def.object(forKey: KDeviceToken) ?? String())
}

// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    NSLog("remoteMessage: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
}
```

Comment: added google plist also ? also try subscribing to a random topic and check if you are getting any notification for that topic.

Comment: yes already added. Even i am not getting test notification from firebase.

Comment: you tried with a topic ?

Comment: yes i tried but no success. Even i created a test demo app in that it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks Sharad now it's working. finally i just changed the Signing options from automatically to manual.